# Bootstrap accordion not collapsing in VueJS

Tags: html, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I've got a bit of a problem here, and i'm not sure how to fix it. It's probably something really small and stupid, but i'm looking over it...

I've got this accordion in bootstrap, and normally the open elements collapse when you select a new one. This is not happening in my version.

Code Below:

```
<template>
  <div class='monsters'>
    <div class="loading" v-if="loading">
      <div class="loading">Loading&#8230;</div>
    </div>
    <div v-if="error" class="error">
        {{ error }}
    </div>
    <ul v-if="monsters">
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default" v-for="monster in monsters">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" :href="'#monster'+monster.id">{{ monster.name }}</a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div :id="'monster'+monster.id" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <monster-lg  v-bind:monster="monster"></monster-lg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

Any ideas on why how etc?

Comment: Why is this tagged Bootstrap 4? Panels only exist in Bootstrap 3.

Comment: That's a very good one, it's probably the mixed versions that is to blame. I'll try it with the card method, and post the results!